# If someone sends you a text message 'I am coming' What does it means?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, grammaticality

How you will recognise sender is male or female ?

Comment: So much room for innuendo...

Comment: More context is needed here.

Comment: But if you receive a text on your phone, don't you have their number on your contact list? How can you not know who the sender is, unless you're in the habit of receiving anonymous texts...?

Comment: @Mari-LouA No I don't have, that's why I asking.

Comment: So it's a text from someone you don't know? then it's a wrong message. It was meant for someone else.

Comment: @medica glad you didn't say "more consext is needed here".

Comment: @ShahabQureshi, Maybe this is a silly question, but in your own native language, if you got a similar message, but did not know the person who sent it to you (unknown number not in your contacts list), would the *language itself* reveal the gender of the person? Obvious jokes aside, is there a man-way of saying "I am coming", and a different, distinct woman-way of saying "I am coming"?

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Medica glad
One of my freelancer client few days ago sent me an email saying 'I will send my resource at your place to discuss project in details. We already have your contact details.'

So I received a message next day saying 'I am from XYZ company to discuss XYZ iOS project. I am coming, I will reach there by 2PM'

Comment: @DanBron - Yes in my native language there is way to distinguish. If someone will say same in my language you can easily identify.
That's why I asked.
Remember, No Question is a Silly Question

Comment: Well you'll find out at 2.00pm. You can always text back and ask for their name and how you will recognize them. I would add this extra info to your post as an addendum.

Comment: @Mari-LouA
haha :D Found smoking hot chick :) Its yesterday's story

Comment: I did NOT upvote the above comment!

Comment: so she already came?

Comment: This question makes sense in ESL.
I suggest it should be migrated. Possibly after an edit.

Answer (score 2):

Either they are on the way to a location (perhaps your location or a location at which you are expecting them) or they are achieving orgasm.

There's no way to tell from the message alone whether the sender is male or female.

[come](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/come)

> 1 *[NO OBJECT, USUALLY WITH ADVERBIAL OF DIRECTION]* 
> Move or travel towards or into a place thought of as near or familiar to the speaker
>
> 6 *[NO OBJECT] informal* 
> Have an orgasm.

The latter meaning can also be used figuratively - the writer is very pleased about some event which has occurred. This usage is definitely slang and would usually be inappropriate in (for example) a formal business letter, a job application, or a PhD thesis.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, I think you're right. I've just deleted it.

Comment: Don't ask me about Memes, until a few years back I thought it was a nickname for Mary :)